# Is this question format valid? (Asking for system info from others)

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I was originally drawn to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387636/python-platform-os-dependant-vars) while trying to clear up "forum-esque" questions where the OP replied using multiple answers.

In short, it asks those who are willing, to run a snippet of code and report the results. The OP has posted multiple answers representing different systems.

I haven't come across this question format before and am not sure it should be on the site. Votes make no sense in this context as all answers are equally correct.

I'm leaning towards voting to close but wondered if others agree?

Comment: I agree; I've apparently voted to close it before, since the system won't allow me to vote to close it now. I don't see how the answers can be useful anyway; this doesn't provide a list of platforms that exist with Python; it provides information about the people who answered the question.

Comment: Hey, good catch

Comment: Heh, a number of questions he's answered are his own. I understand that answering your own questions is encouraged (provided you have an answer) but his track-record is quite unfitting of this community's format so it seems.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the query to find forum-stlye answers [is available here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/100536/forum-esque-multiple-answers)

Comment: @Bracketworks I don't like this question any more than you do, but the OP only has one other self answered question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's so many ways to close that question:

- it's clearly non-constructive, as no one answer is more correct than the others
- it's also pretty much the very definition of "too localized"
- I would even argue it's not on-topic, as there is already a Code Review site

Answer (score 3):

I would think [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be the best site for that kind of question.  While I think some will call it a list question (and they wouldn't be far wrong), I think it's a pretty ingenious use of the system.  Having said that I don't see how it could possibly fit in a Q&A system, but I'd check the [Code Review Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/) to see if they like that kind of stuff.